# How to list the fonts used in an adobe illustrator (AI) file, on linux?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, font-management, linux

I would like to list font names used inside an Adobe Illustrator (CS4 or CS5 I don't remember) file, on my Fedora linux desktop.

Is it possible ? I tried to open it with Inkscape but I fail to see where the information is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the suffix of an `.ai` file to `.txt` then open it in any text editor.

Within the text file there are declarations for fonts:

`<stFnt:fontName>SuperCoolFontNamedHere</stFnt:fontName>`

I can't speak for Fedora specifically, but surely there's a method to search text files.

Comment: file extension is meaningless on linux for most part. PS you can also do this with ghostscript but yeah grep or sed will do.

Comment: Yep, opening the file with kwrite and such does the trick, no need to change the extension though.

Comment: Yeah, no experience with Linux here. On the Mac, you have to change the extension for *some* text applications so they don't just show the PDF part of the file (Like BBEdit).

Comment: So if one runs `sed -n -e '/<stFnt\:fontName>/ s/.*<stFnt\:fontName>\(.*\)<\/.*/\1/p' file.ai` you get a nice font listing. Now im off to list all the fonts Ive ever used in ai files.

Comment: I'm just facing an '.ai' file which supposedly contains text, but no `stFnt` tags whatsoever. Instead it looks like it contains a PDF, perhaps because it has been created in [PDF compatibility mode](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12557/155159).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of fonts that come with Illustrator CS4

http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/fontinstall/cs4installedfonts.html#Standard_Install_Set

Here is a list of windows system fonts

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: I don't *really* think this is what's being asked. I read the question and it seems to me B2F wants to know the fonts used **within** a *specific* AI file.